# Open the registry permission dialog

Tags: c#, permissions, registry

I used `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` to open the content of a `RegistryKey` in my application. Now I want to provide the Microsoft Permission Dialog (In regedit.exe: right-click on a key -> Permissions...) for the registry key to the users of my application. Is there any way to call this dialog within a c# application?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 2):

This may be a pretty complicated task in C#.

After some looking, it appears that `regedit` shows the permissions dialog (internally in `RegEdit_InvokeSecurityEditor`) by calling [`EditSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446618.aspx) from ACLUI.dll.

That function "displays a property sheet that contains a [basic security property page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376377.aspx)." It requires you to pass an implementation of [`ISecurityInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378900.aspx) for actually manipulating properties of objects.

After searching for ["EditSecurity C#"](http://www.google.com/search?q=EditSecurity%20c#) I found a couple interesting results:

- [Access Control List Editing in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163832.aspx)

I don't believe there is any simple .NET way to pass a `RegistryKey` object to some function and get a dialog box to edit its permissions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. I hoped there is an easier way then programming my own security dialog, that the reason why i asked for calling the windows internal dialog. But i think there is no easier way...